# Ring extensions, Units, Jacobson radical

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Consider the following problem:

Problem: Let $A\subseteq B$ be an integral extension of rings. Show that:

(a) Let $a\in A$. If $a\in B^{\times} $, then $a\in A^{\times}$.

(b) Let $M\in Spm A$ be a maximal ideal in A and let $S_M =A/M$. Then the natural map $B/MB \to S^{-1}_M( B /MB) $ is an isomorphism.

(c) $M_A= M_B \cap A$, where $M_A$ and $M_B$ denote the Jacobson -radical of A and B.

Solution: (a) I tried by attempting to prove the contrapositive. Let $a\notin A^{\times}$. Then I have to show that that $a \notin B^{\times}$.

I have been given that for $a\in A$ there doesn't exists $ x\in A$ such that ax=1. I have to show that in B also there will not exists an x. Let on the contrary in B there exists such an x ie $ax=1$. But I am not able to proceed from here on.

(b) Can you please tell what function will define this natural map?

(c) I can take one element in set on RHS and LHS respectively and then show it in LHS and RHS respectively.

But, Can you please tell me a more elegant way of proving this using a result rather than this?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't really understand point b). What is the map? You use the term "map" to refer to $B/MB$ and "$B/MB\in S^{-1}_B(B/MB)$" doesn't make sense. Also, $A/M$ means the quotient, I think you mean $A\setminus B$ (the set-theoretic complement of $M$ in $A$)

Comment: @Alessandro term map is given in the part (b) of the question.

Comment: My confusion is exactly on how part (b) is worded. What is the map you're looking for? At least, what are the domain and codomain? (For example, it's a map from the set of maximal ideals to some other set of ideals). If you can talk about a "natural map", it means you already have a function (it is said "map"), otherwise you only have a statement like "set $A$ is naturally bijective to set $B$", in which case is legitimate to ask what is this natural bijection, but then what are the sets $A,B$ in your question? That is, in point (b) this "natural map" goes from where to where?

Comment: @Alessandro I have edited it, there was a typo. Kindly have a look.

Answer (score 2):

- a) is usually proven by using that if $a\in B^\times$, then there is a polynomial $x^{n+1}+b_nx^n+\cdots+b_0\in A[x]$ vanishing at $a^{-1}$, so plug $a^{-1}$ inside the polynomial and multiply by $a^{n+1}$ and (can you continue from here?)

> You get $$1+b_na+\cdots+b_0a^{n+1}=1+\underbrace{(b_n+\cdots+b_0a^n)}_{f(a)}a=0\tag{*}$$and $f(a)\in A$ (since $a$ and the coefficients belongs to $A$) and (*) implies that $f(a)=-a^{-1}$.

- Let $\mathfrak m\subseteq A$ be the maximal ideal. You write $S_\mathfrak m=A/\mathfrak m$, which is a standard notation for the quotient of $A$ by $\mathfrak m$, which is a subset of $B/\mathfrak mB$, but you don't want to localize at $S_\mathfrak m$ because it contains $0$ and if you invert $0$ then you get the zero ring $\{0\}$. I guess you mean $S=S_\mathfrak m=A\setminus\mathfrak m$ (the set-theoretic complement) sitting inside $B$. In this case, the map $i: B/\mathfrak mB \rightarrow S^{-1}B/\mathfrak mB$ is the canonical map from a ring to its localization at some multiplicative set (in this case $S$ is the image of $S\subseteq B$ under the projection $\pi:B\rightarrow B/\mathfrak mB$, so I'm denoting with $S$ both the multiplicative set $A\setminus\mathfrak m$ inside $B$ and $\pi(S)$ inside $B/\mathfrak mB$). To prove that the localization is an isomorphism, you can prove that all the elements in $S$ are already invertible in $B/\mathfrak mB$. This is a consequence of the [universal property of localization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_(commutative_algebra)#Universal_property). But, since $\mathfrak m$ is a maximal ideal, it means that for every $x\notin\mathfrak m$ there is $y\in A$ such that $xy-1\in\mathfrak m$ (this is spelling out the fact that $A/\mathfrak m$ is a field and $x+\mathfrak m\in A/\mathfrak m$ is non zero, hence a unit), but then $xy-1\in \mathfrak mB$, so $[x][y]=1$ is also true in $B/\mathfrak mB$, which means that $[x]=x+\mathfrak mB$ is a unit, for every $[x]\in S_\mathfrak m$, which is what we wanted: Every class $[x]\in S$ is already invertible and the canonical map $i$ is an isomorphism. Why do we need that $A\rightarrow B$ is an integral extension? I think we don't really need it, because if the extension is not integral, it may be that $\mathfrak mB=B$ (take, for example, $\mathbb Z\hookrightarrow\mathbb Q$) and so the rings $B/\mathfrak mB$ and $S^{-1}B/\mathfrak mB$ became zero rings (in which case $i$ is clearly an isomorphism), but the argument is still valid.
- For this you need to prove that *Every maximal ideal in $A$ is the preimage of a maximal ideal in $B$ and conversely that the preimage of a maximal ideal in $B$ is maximal in $A$*. First, let me show how the previous statement implies $\text{rad}_A=A\cap\text{rad}_B$ (where $\text{rad}_A$ is the Jacobson radical, that is, the intersection of all maximal ideals in $A$). Since $A\cap\mathfrak m'$ is a maximal ideal, for every $\mathfrak m'\in\text{Spm}(B)=$maximal spectrum of $B$, then clearly $$\text{rad}_A\subseteq A\cap \text{rad}_B$$(because if $x$ belongs to every maximal ideal of $A$, then it also belongs to every maximal ideal of the form $A\cap \mathfrak m$, with $\mathfrak m\in\text{Spm}(B)$, hence $x\in A\cap\text{rad}_B$). On the other hand, every maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$ of $A$ is of the form $A\cap\mathfrak m'$, for some $\mathfrak m'\in\text{Spm}(B)$, so clearly $$A\cap \text{rad}_B\subseteq\text{rad}_A$$ and so $\text{rad}_A=B\cap \text{rad}_B$. You can look at the proof of my initial statement [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1110785/integral-ring-extension-maximal-ideals).

Comment: you didn't told how such a polynomial will exist in line 2 of your answer of part (a)?

Comment: Because $B$ is integral over $A$

Comment: You are right for (b). I didn't meant the quotient ring.

Comment: "To prove that the localization is an isomorphism, you can prove that all the elements in S are already invertible in B/mB. " WHy to prove that localization is an isomorphism , I should prove that elements in S are already inverible in B/MB?

Comment: In general, if $S$ is a set of units in $R$, then $S^{-1}R$ will be isomorphic to $R$. Look at how $S^{-1}R$ is constructed and you see that if the elements of $S$, then $$\frac{r}{s}=\frac{s^{-1}r}{1},\forall r\in R,s\in S$$so $R\hookrightarrow S^{-1}R$ is surjective and injective (it is injective, in general, as soon as $S$ doesn't contain zero divisors, like in the case of $S$ being a set of units)